# Specific published image of the Wolf-In-Sheep's-Clothing

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, content-identification

I am trying to track down color art for the Wolf-In-Sheep's-Clothing (first appearance in *S3: Expedition to the Barrier Peaks*). I believe I first saw it some time since around 2013.

Things I remember:

- The color image had a watercolor-ish soft-edge, I would say “gentle”, style on a white background.
- For some reason I associate it with the top left location on a page spread.
- The image was not the S3 module artwork by Erol Otus, and was not in Otus' style.
- The color scheme was somewhat like Otus' color plates in *S3*, but perhaps featuring a little more brown.

I believe the illustration I recall appeared in an actual gaming publication, but am not 100% certain. However, the artwork does not appear in:

- The original *S3: Expedition to the Barrier Peaks*
- The 1st edition *Monster Manual II*
- The 2nd edition *Monstrous Compendium* vols 1–2, *Annual* vols 1–4, *Fiend Folio Appendix*, or *Outer Planes Appendix*
- The 3.5th edition *Monster Manual* vols I–V
- The *Pathfinder Bestiary 3* or Pathfinder's *Misfit Monsters Redeemed*
- The 4th edition *Monster Manual*
- The 5th edition *Monster Manual*, *Volo’s Guide to Monsters*, *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, or *Mordenkainen's Feindish Folio*

Not being able to find this image is driving me batty. Can you help?

Comment: Do you remember the timeframe for when you saw the image? Was it an original publication, or a fan-made print? Erol's style is... _unique_, let's say that, and I'm having trouble finding something similar to this on my searches for his images.

Comment: @T.Sar Thank you! The art was not in Otus' style (which I dig, personally :). I have edited this point and my time frame (seen some time over the past decade) into my question.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes. I will edit to make that explicit.

Comment: Have you seen the versions on deviant art?

Answer (score 4):

A web search finds this image by [Tenebraestudios on furaffinity.net](https://www.furaffinity.net/view/20923857/):

[image: wolf-in-sheep’s-clothing watercolor]

Comments on the page indicate that Tenebraestudios has been published in RPG materials (e.g. Fantasy Flight publications), but not, apparently, in D&D, and presumably not with this work. Rather, the description just says it’s “Based on an old monster from DnD.”

But this is the only illustration of a wolf-in-sheep’s-clothing that has a watercolor or “soft edge” look to it, at least as far as Google can find. It’s also not any of those you list as not being the work you’re looking for. It doesn’t have a white background, but at least some places include it with the background cropped—e.g. [this YouTube video has it so cropped in its preview pane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92pxroIHg8g):

[image: Dungeon Dad Monster-of-the-Week Wolf-in-sheep’s-clothing Video Preview Panel]

So it still *just might* be what you’re thinking of.

Comment: +1 This is a lovely image! Pretty sure it is not it, but a swell find.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some extra digging, I found the following image which I think matches the OP description a little better, as well as not being in any of the listed references. This comes from the [Tome of Horrors Revised](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/3019/Tome-of-Horrors-Revised) (2005), page 372.

[image]

Comment: That is a great image! Is there a color version of it?

Comment: @Lexible - I saw your edit, I haven't been able to find a color version of this. There are newer, color versions of the ToH, but I don't have those personally.